# Ideal diode for 0-5V range for measurement circuit

Tags: diodes, current-measurement, rectifier, voltage-measurement, energy-harvesting

I am building a measurement circuit that measures the voltage/current from a thermogenerator. The expected measurement range (and therefore input voltage range) is 0-5V. I plan to measure it with a Texas Instruments [INA260 chip](https://www.ti.com/product/INA260), unfortunately it is sensitive to reverse polarity. Therefore, I am looking for an ideal diode circuit that works in the input voltage range of 0-5V. The project assumes that it is possible to supply such a diode with an external voltage.  I was thinking about using Texas Instruments [SM74611](https://www.ti.com/product/SM74611) chip, but it has a minimum voltage of 0.5V, which makes it useless for me (I am interested in voltage measurement also in the range of 0 - 0.5V). Do you perhaps have an idea how to solve my problem?

EDITED:

Here I present the simplified circuit diagram, and the visualization of my problem. The TEG is working under certain thermal difference across it, and then it gives a given voltage on its terminals. However, when something will go wrong and the thermal gradient will change to opposite direction - the output voltage of the TEG also will change the polarity. I want to make sure, that if such an event occurs my circuit won't break. My goal is to measure the voltage and current with INA260 only if the polarity as not reversed. In the diagram beside the circuit it is how voltage on the TEG depends on the temperatures applied to its plates.

[image: Simplified circuit diagram with the TEG and the INA260 IC. The "Ideal diode circuit" is needed as the TEG can give reverse polarized voltage on its outputs, as the thermal gradient across the TEG changes.]

Comment: Can your thermogenerator even produce reverse polarity? You say it like it is a given but to me, it seems much more likely it is not even an issue.. You probably need a small negative supply anyways (-0.7V maybe ) if you truly wish to measure to 0V. Also, ever heard of ESD clamp/protection diodes? Read up how they work. Ideal diode is probably not what you want.

Comment: It is unclear what your objection to the INA260 is. It does not sense negative polarity but you are not asking for that. Please clarify.

Comment: The question needs to be clearer - it says you are asking for a "Diode". Surely you mean device, IC or circuit.

Comment: Post your circuit

Comment: @DKNguyen
Thanks for your insights, and sorry for maybe being not so clear. I have posted my circuit with some more detailed description and example scenario which I need to handle.

Comment: Do you know the output impedance of your TEG? If it is very high you can use the high output impedance with the internal ESD clamping diodes on the INA260. If it's not high impedance, you can add a series resistor to limit current, or you can add external ESD clamping diodes as well. But all these will affect the bandwidth of your reading in one way or another via the RC filter.

Comment: @DKNguyen Unfortunately I don't know the output impedance of the TEG with which this circuit will be used, it should be compatible with different TEGs. However, TEGs have in general low internal resistance of less than 10 Ohm (only few models on the market have internal resistance over 10 Ohms), and gives DC Voltage on the output. My task is just to build TEG output voltage and current measurement circuit, with the protection from reverse polarity.